# Setting A Generator As The Argument Of A PyQt4 Signal

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to use a generator as the argument passed by a PyQt4 signal, and I am not sure as to the cleanest way. I could just do something like `elementChosen=QtCore.pyqtSignal(type((i for i in xrange (i))))`, but this just looks ugly. Any suggestions?

Comment: `type(i for i in xrange(10))` is sufficient. No need for extra set of parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `types` module to make the code look less ugly.

```
from types import GeneratorType

elementChosen = QtCore.pyqtSignal(GeneratorType)
```

documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/types.html